# Partial Derivative Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given with the function: $ f(x,y) = \frac{y\ln(1+x^2 + ay^2) } {x^2 + 2y^2} $ when $ (x,y)\neq (0,0)$, and $f(0,0)=0$ .

There is another given data; $ f_y (0,0) = 2 $ . 
What is the value of $a$ ?

I've tried computing the limit $  \frac{f(0,h)- f(0,0)}{h} $ , but it seems like it's always zero, contradicting the fact that $f_y(0,0)=2 $ !

Can someone help me understand my mistake?

Thanks !

Comment: A number followed by an exclamation mark reminds me of factorial5!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
f_y(0, 0) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0, h) - f(0, 0)} h\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0, h)} h\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac a 2 \frac {\ln(1 + ah^2)} {ah^2}\\ 
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac a 2 \frac {\ln(1 + h)} {h}\\
&= \frac a 2 \left. \frac {d} {dx} \right |_{x=1} \ln x\\
&= \frac a 2
\end{align}
$$
Since $f_y(0, 0) = 2$, $a$ must be $4$.

Comment: Dear @Albert: 
There's a fallacy in what you wrote. When substituting y=h, you don't get $ \frac{a}{2} $ outside the fraction, but $\frac{h}{2 }$ ! In addition, you'll get in the denominator $2h^2 $ and not $ah^2$ .

Comment: @joshua: $$\displaystyle \frac {f(0, h)} h = \frac 1 h \frac {h \ln(1 + ah^2)} {2h^2}
= \frac {\ln(1 + ah^2)} {2h^2} = \frac a 2 \frac {\ln(1 + ah^2)} {ah^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

What about a direct L'Hospital (=L'H)?:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}f(0,h)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\rlap{/}h}\frac{\rlap{/}h\log(1+ah^2)}{2ah^2}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\rlap{/}2a\rlap{/}h}{1+ah^2}\frac{1}{\rlap{/_2}4\,\,\,\rlap{/}h}=\frac{a}{2}$$